# Execute bash script from docker

Tags: python-3.x, bash, docker

I am having a bash script, that is running inside a docker container.
This bash script is invoked by my wrapper python script. Arguments are passed through python script.
Bash script has a line to do ssh and get the result out.
When I am running this, I am not getting ssh output in my host terminal, from where I am running the script.

This is my section of bash script

```
function query_function () {
    test_variable1=`curl -ks "$sp_hostname" | grep ",active" | egrep -v "$excluded_hostnames" | egrep "[.,]$1" | egrep ",$2| $2" | cut -d "," -f 2 | sort`
    for f in `echo $test_variable1`; do
        output=''
        echo 'SERVER:' $f
        ssh -i "key_file" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -q $f "$3"
        echo $'\n'
    done
    exit 0
}
```

This is how I call my docker container to run script.

```
$ docker run -it --rm --net host nnarayanan-wrapper morpheus vm appdb 'command'
```

1) Confirmed python script invokes bash script
2) Confirmed that bash script is taking the passed arguments
3) I am not getting any output while doing an ssh inside a docker container through bash script in my host machine terminal

Answer (score 0):

Most likely in your image you do not have a `curl` and `egrep`.

So I suggest you add to your Dockerfile this:

```
...
# Install prerequisites
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl egrep
...
```

I hope it will help.